# homestead.rb:109:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: laravel, homestead

I try to use homestead via the document 5.3 from the offical website
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead
but it doesn't work, the details were as follows :
C:\Users\liang\Homestead>vagrant up
C:/Users/liang/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:109:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/liang/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Users/liang/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:109:in`block (2 levels) in configure'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in`add_config'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:321:in `provision'
        from C:/Users/liang/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:106:in`block in configure'
        from C:/Users/liang/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:105:in `each'
        from C:/Users/liang/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:105:in`configure'
        from C:/Users/liang/Homestead/Vagrantfile:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in`call'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in`block (2 levels) in load'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in`block in load'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in`load'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in`new'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in`host'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in`call'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in`hook'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/bin/vagrant:177:in`ensure in '
        from D:/Program Files/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/bin/vagrant:177:in `'

[The screencaputure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le7rr.jpg)

Who can help me! Thank you

Comment: who can help me? (┬＿┬)

Comment: This link may be helpful: http://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2014-problem-launching-vagrant-on-homestead

Answer (score 3):

OK，I have solved the error
start git bash and then
$ ssh-keygen

Comment: Could you write it step by step?

Comment: First install git

Comment: 1.install git. 2. open your home directory.3 right key of your mouse 'Git bash here'  4.ssh-keygen