# Laravel Homestead ssh error

Tags: php, laravel

When I want to setup Laravel Homestead and add vagrant up to Homestead This

```
Error occurred:
Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:118:in`read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Hanie/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)
from C:/Windows/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:118:in`block (2 levels) in configure'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:336:in `provision'
from C:/Windows/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:115:in `block in configure'
from C:/Windows/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:114:in `each'
from C:/Windows/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:114:in `configure'
from C:/Windows/Homestead/Vagrantfile:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'                            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
 from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'                             from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
 from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `new'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `vagrantfile'
 from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `host'
 from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:214:in `block in action_runner'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
 from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:479:in `hook'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:728:in `unload'
 from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/bin/vagrant:130:in `ensure in <main>'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/bin/vagrant:130:in `<main>'
```

and my Homestead.yaml is here:
What is Wrong?

[image: Homestead.yaml]

Comment: do you actually have a ssh key in C:/Users/Hanie/.ssh ? also C:\laravel projects should be C:/laravel-projects or ~/laravel-projects I use ~ in my yaml files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.install git. 
2. open your home directory.
3 right key of your mouse 'Git bash here' 
4.ssh-keygen

from:
[homestead.rb:109:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234219/homestead-rb109in-read-no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sysopen)